# How do i setup android webdriver to work with selenium grid?

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

Currently I have an android device running the WebDriver.apk app for mobile testing. I'd like to incorporate these devices into a larger test lab through the use of selenium grid/node setup. Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation on this. The android WebDriver.apk makes use of RemoteWebDriverServer I believe, but I do not know how to register this with a node or even directly to a grid. Has anyone accomplished this? If so can you provide some direction?

Comment: http://blargon7.com/2011/12/hooking-android-up-to-the-selenium-grid/